# Ektron CMS asp.net : How to get list of child taxonomies under parent taxonomy recursively

Tags: ektron

I'm working on Ektron CMS asp.net web forms(not mvc).

I want to get list of child taxonomies under parent taxonomy recursively.

Could anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization;
using Ektron.Cms.Organization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Code:

```
long parentID = 2147486197; // This is the parent taxonomy's ID

TaxonomyManager taxMan = new TaxonomyManager();
TaxonomyCriteria criteria = new TaxonomyCriteria();
criteria.AddFilter(TaxonomyProperty.ParentId, Ektron.Cms.Common.CriteriaFilterOperator.EqualTo, parentID);
List<Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyData> resultsList = taxMan.GetList(criteria);
```